# Underfull hbox error on tabular context

Tags: tables

I am having a problem with the following document, pdflatex is continuously complaining with `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in alignment at lines 3--7` in this sample, but it does for many more lines in the original doc.

I've read it has to do with the `\\` in the code, but as far as I know it is the way of finishing a row in a tabular context, and if I remove them it does not compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{0.9\textwidth}{l}
  \hline
  Test \\
  \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I made your example a lot smaller. This makes the problem far easier to pinpoint (one could also remove the two `\hline` and the `\\`, but that would make your text nonsensical.

Comment: That \ should be `\\ ` (stupid comment markup).

Comment: @Caramdir Oops.  Fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LaTeX is essentially telling you that you want a table with `\textwidth` size, but only provide content that is 4 characters long. Maybe the following example shows where the problem is:

```
\begin{tabular*}{0.9\textwidth}{|l|}
  \hline
  Test \\
  \hline
\end{tabular*}
```

This produces

[image: result]

which is usually not the intended outcome. The easiest way to fix this is to use the `tabularx` environment from the package of the same name and use the `X` column type (which adds filling space).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{|X|}
  \hline
  Test\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: result with tabularx]

---

The reason that your example does not compile without `\\` is that `\hline` has to be placed at the beginning of a row. Removing both `\\` and the following `\hline` compiles, but shows the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

It is the way how you are using `tabular*`. It makes no sense to have the starred version with only one column. In such a case one should use the unstarred version with the `p`-column specifier. With at least two columns for `tabular*` you didn't get underfull boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{0.9\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}\hline
  Test & Test\\\hline
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{p{0.9\textwidth}}\hline
  Test \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```